# Unable to access h2 console using Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on a **Spring Boot application** that recently migrated from **Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3**. The application uses **Spring Security 6**. However, after the migration, I am encountering an HTTP 403 error when trying to access the H2 console.

In my project, I have configured my **SecurityFilterChain** to allow access to certain public endpoints, including the H2 console.

```
@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            
            .authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) ->
                authorize
                
                    .requestMatchers(
                        "/api/auth/login",
                        "/api/auth/logout",
                        "/login",
                        "/h2-console/**"
                        ).permitAll()
                
                    .requestMatchers("/admin/**")
                        .hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                    
                    .anyRequest()
                        .authenticated()
                        
            ).logout((logout) ->
                logout
                    .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                    .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                    .logoutUrl("/api/auth/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl("/logout-success")
                    
            ).headers((headers) ->
                headers
                    .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin())
            )
        ;
        return http.build();
        }
```

When I start the application, the **H2 console is available**, and I can confirm it with the following log message::

```
[2m2023-05-22T23:36:52.924+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[  restartedMain][0;39m [36mo.s.b.a.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m H2 console available at '/h2-console'. Database available at 'jdbc:h2:~/test'
```

I am able to access the allowed endpoints without any issues. However, when I try to access the H2 console, I receive an HTTP 403 error
[image]

But I can't access to my h2-console (I get an 403 HTTP code):
[image]

I have also tried ignoring the requestMatcher for the H2 console since it has its own login access, but I am unable to identify the root cause of the problem. Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return (web) -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/h2-console/**");
    }
```

When I attempt to access the H2 console URL, I can see the following debug information in my console:

```
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.983+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.985+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.985+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.986+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.987+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.987+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36mo.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to ResourceHttpRequestHandler [classpath [META-INF/resources/], classpath [resources/], classpath [static/], classpath [public/], ServletContext [/]]
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.989+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.990+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.990+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.991+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.991+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
[2m2023-05-22T23:45:07.991+02:00[0;39m [32mDEBUG[0;39m [35m8128[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[nio-8080-exec-8][0;39m [36ms.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
```

Somebody can help me with this problem? Sorry for my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring security 6 changed a bit around requestMatchers, it behaves somehow differently from requestAntMatchers.

You should add this to your builder, it will do the trick.

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.PathRequest;
...

authorize.requestMatchers(PathRequest.toH2Console()).permitAll();
```

Comment: Yes! It works thanks. I read some configurations but I didn't find the difference between using PathRequest vs String paths. After that, It's clear that there are differences.